# How can I assign ButtKnife @OnClick to two different views with the same id?

Tags: android, android-fragments, butterknife

For example,

Assume that I have 2 buttons with the same ID in two different fragment layouts.

layout1 - myButtonAction
layout2 - myButtonAction

In the parent activity if I do this:

```
@OnClick(R.id.myButtonAction)
public void doSomething() {
   // Only the button in first layout works
}
```

Any suggestions regarding this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not bind the click event within the fragment's code? If you need to do something at the activity level you can implement a callbacks pattern.

Comment: The onclick does the same thing, I'm trying to reuse the code